# Remove column name from chart title in sns.relplot and keep only horizontal grid line

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to create a diverging dot plot with python and I am using seaborn relplot to do the small multiples with one of the columns.

The datasouce is MakeoverMonday 2018w18:
[MOM2018w48](https://data.world/makeovermonday/2018w48)

I got this far with this code:

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
g=sns.relplot(x=cost ,y=city, col=item, s=120, size = cost, hue = cost, col_wrap= 2)
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

which generates this:
[image: relplot dot plot]

So, far, so good.
Now, I want only horizontal gridlines, sort it and get rid of the column name ('item'=) in the small multiple charts. Any ideas?

This is what I am trying to recreate:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get reasonably close by just using Matplotlib (no seaborn). Matplotlib is sometimes a little more low-level, but this also allows a lot of customization to be done.

There's definitely still some hacky-things going on to mimic the appearance of your example image as close as possible. Perhaps there are more elegant ways to get there.

Having a DataFrame structured as:
[image]

Creating the plot with:

```py
colors = {"Taxi": "C2", "Club entry": "C0", "Big Mac": "C3"}

fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [["Taxi", "Club entry", "Big Mac"]], figsize=(12, 4.5), sharey=True, sharex=True, 
    facecolor="w", dpi=86,
)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1, wspace=0.1)

for name in axs:
    
    # subset dataframe
    df_subset = df.query(f"Item == '{name}'")
    
    axs[name].set_title(name, size=14, alpha=.5)
    line, = axs[name].plot(
        "Cost", "City", "o", data=df_subset,
        ms=24, color=colors[name],
    )
    
    # add value inside the circle (marker)
    for i, cost_value in enumerate(df_subset["Cost"].to_list()):
        axs[name].text(
            cost_value, i, f"${cost_value:1.0f}", ha="center", va="center",
            weight="bold", color="w", alpha=.8, size=10,
        )        
        
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.values()):
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("${x:1.0f}"))
    ax.grid(axis="y", linewidth=3, alpha=0.5)
    ax.grid(axis="x", linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.5)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0, labelcolor="#00000077")
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
    
    for sp in ax.spines:
        ax.spines[sp].set_visible(False)
        
    if i == 0: # only applies to the left axis
        ax.set_yticklabels([]) # hide default labels
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.FixedLocator(range(len(df_subset))))
        
        # add yticklabels manually (for alignment...)
        yticklabels = [(f"{x:<20s}", f"${y:<3.0f}") for x,y in list(df_subset[["City", "Total Cost"]].to_records(index=False))]

        for ypos, (city_name, total_cost) in enumerate(yticklabels):
            # negative x-offset is in units "Total Cost"
            ax.text(-18, ypos, city_name, ha="left", va="center", alpha=.5)
            ax.text(-5, ypos, total_cost, ha="left", va="center", alpha=.9)
```

[image]

Comment: By using subplot_mosaic you are hardcoding the plots right? Can it be done dynamic?

Comment: Yes probably, but you would need to specify somewhere which items need to be plotted? I just picked 3 to match the amount in the example plot.   

I use `subplot_mosiac` since it allows you to identify the axes with a name (instead of a number). And if that name matches the DataFrame, you can automatically "lookup" the data that needs to be plotted.

Comment: I want to use the python visuals in Power BI and have it respond to the filters in the pane. So the data will be passed by a dataframe created dynamically by power bi. It is of course ok in this case, as i know the values before hand and they wont change, but with real data, I would need the subplots to be created dynamically.
I will give your method a go and see what I come up with :)

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand what that would look like. But the amount/type needs to come from somewhere? In this example `df["Item"].unique()` would provide all items that could be plotted on an axis (but it's a lot more than the current 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through `g.axes_dict` and change the individual subplots. The `sizes=` parameter sets the size of the smallest and largest dots. Note that seaborn often works more intuitively if you use the `data=` parameter to indicate the dataframe, and then refer to the rest of the parameters via their column name.

Here is an example using seaborn's `tips` dataset:

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
g = sns.relplot(data=tips, x='tip', y='day', col='time', size='tip', sizes=(50, 300), hue='tip', col_wrap=2,
                legend=False)
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
for item, ax in g.axes_dict.items():
     ax.grid(False, axis='x')
     ax.set_title(item)  # or ax.set_title('') to remove the title entirely
```

[image: seaborn looping through axes_dict]

Here is another example, adding text to the dots.  The new example has only one dot per y-value, as otherwise there would be too many texts on top of each other:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df = tips.groupby(by=['day', 'time'])['tip'].mean().reset_index()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

g = sns.relplot(data=df, x='tip', y='day', col='time', size='tip', sizes=(500, 1000), hue='tip', col_wrap=2,
                palette='blend:crimson,dodgerblue', legend=False)
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
for time, ax in g.axes_dict.items():
     ax.grid(False, axis='x')
     ax.set_title(time)
     for day in df['day'].cat.categories:
          mean_tip = list(df[(df['day'] == day) & (df['time'] == time)]['tip'])[0]
          print(time, day, mean_tip, np.isnan(mean_tip))
          if not np.isnan(mean_tip):
               ax.text(x=mean_tip, y=day, s=f'{mean_tip:.1f}', ha='center', va='center', color='yellow')
```

[image: adding texts to a seaborn scatter plot]

Comment: Do you know how how to add labels to the markers? Have tried but cant figure it out.
Also, why did my set_styles not work? Because I wasnt using the data parameter? (new to python)

Comment: To add labels, you need to loop through each subplot and add a text.  Your `set_style` did work, creating a grid in x and y direction.  The call to `ax.grid(False, axis='x')` removes the vertical grid.

Comment: Conceptually I get it, but I only managed to get the labels on the last chart.

Comment: I added an example with text inside the dots

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`seaborn.FacetGrid.set_titles`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.set_titles.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.set_titles):

```py
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
g = sns.relplot(x=cost ,y=city, hue=cost, s=120, size=cost,
                col=item, col_wrap=2)
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
g.set_titles(template="{col_name}")
```

Comment: If you use the `row` keyword remember to use `g.set_titles(template="{row_name}")` accordingly