# Dynamic pandas subplots with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I need help creating subplots in matplotlib dynamically from a pandas dataframe.
The data I am using is from [data.word](https://data.world/makeovermonday/2018w48).

I have already created the viz but the plots  [have been created manually](https://github.com/Curbal-Data-Labs/Matplotlib-Labs/blob/master/Dot%20plot/Dot%20plot%20small%20multiples.ipynb).

[image]

The reason why I need it dynamically is because I am going to apply a filter dynamically (in Power BI) and i need the graph to adjust to the filter.

This is what i have so far:
I imported the data and got it in the shape i need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as 

# read file from makeover monday year 2018 week 48
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Ruth Pozuelo\Documents\python_examples\data\2018w48.csv',  usecols=["city", "category","item", "cost"], index_col=False, decimal=",")
df.head()
```

this is the table:
[image]

I then apply the filter that will come from Power BI dynamically:

```
df = df[df.category=='Party night']
```

and then I count the number of plots based on the number of items I get after I apply the filter:

```
itemCount = df['item'].nunique()         #number of plots
```

If I then plot the subplots:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=itemCount ,figsize=(30,10), sharey=True)
```

I get the skeleton:
[image]

So far so good!
But now i am suck on how to feed the x axis to the loop to generate the subcategories. I am trying something like below, but nothing works.

```
#for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
 #   ax.plot(??,cityValues, marker='o',markersize=25, lw=0, color="green") # The top-left axes
```

As I already have the code for the look and feel of the chart, annotations,ect, I would love to be able to use the plt.subplots method and I prefer not use seaborn if possible.

Any ideas on how to get his working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The list of columns and subplots to be processed can be looped through to organize the processing of the graph. Sorry if I am wrong as I don't want to register as a member to get the data. `fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,5, figsize=(30,10), sharey=True)
colors = ['green','blue','red','black','brown']
for i, (ax,column,c) in enumerate(zip(axes.flatten(), df.columns[1:], colors)):
    ax.plot(df[column], df['City'], marker='o', markersize=25, lw=0, color=c)
    ax.set_title(col)
    for i,j in zip(df[column], City):
        ax.annotate('$'+str(i), xy=(i, j),xytext =(i-4,j),...)`

Comment: I forgot you need to register. I uploaded the file here: https://github.com/Curbal-Data-Labs/Matplotlib-Labs/blob/master/2018w48.csv

Tried your code but not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data was presented to us and we used it as the basis for our code. I prepared a list of columns and a list of coloring and looped through them. axes.rabel() is more memory efficient than axes.fatten(). This is because the list contains an object for each subplot, allowing for centralized configuration.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Curbal-Data-Labs/Matplotlib-Labs/master/2018w48.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)

dataset.drop_duplicates(['city','item'], inplace=True)
dataset.pivot_table(index='city', columns='item', values='cost', aggfunc='sum', margins = True).sort_values('All', ascending=True).drop('All', axis=1)

df = dataset.pivot_table(index='city', columns='item', values='cost', aggfunc='sum', margins = True).sort_values('All', ascending=True).drop('All', axis=1).sort_values('All', ascending=False, axis=1).drop('All').reset_index()

# comma replace
for c in df.columns[1:]:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(30,10), sharey=True)

colors = ['green','blue','red','black','brown'] 
col_names = ['Dinner','Drinks at Dinner','2 Longdrinks','Club entry','Cinema entry']

for i, (ax,col,c) in enumerate(zip(axes.ravel(), col_names, colors)):
    ax.plot(df.loc[:,col], df['city'], marker='o', markersize=25, lw=0, color=c)
    ax.set_title(col)
    for i,j in zip(df[col], df['city']):
        ax.annotate('$'+str(i), xy=(i, j), xytext=(i-4,j), color="white", fontsize=8)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.spines[['top', 'right', 'left', 'bottom']].set_visible(False)
    ax.grid(True, axis='y', linestyle='solid', linewidth=2)
    ax.grid(True, axis='x', linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.2)
    ax.xaxis.tick_top() 
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
    ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=160)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter('${x:1.0f}')
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=8, top=False, left=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: oh, i see what you did there, of course I can pivot the table after filtering it.
Question: is there a way to do the plots without pivoting the table?

Comment: If it does not pivot, the item column is filtered and processed. For example. `items = ['Dinner','Drinks at Dinner','2 Longdrinks','Club entry','Cinema entry']
for i in items:
    df = dataset.query('item == @i')
    print(df.head())`

Comment: You pivoted items, right? I was hoping to pick the items from the column without pivoting them to avoid that step and understand if it could be done.
In this step: 
`df = dataset.pivot_table(index='city', columns='item', values='cost', aggfunc='sum', margins = True).sort_values('All', ascending=True).drop('All', axis=1).sort_values('All', ascending=False, axis=1).drop('All').reset_index()`

Comment: I understood by your comment that there is a way to not convert wide format data frames, so I answered that we can just loop through the items we want to extract in long format data frames. Am I not understanding your comment?

Comment: I am not explaining myself, apologies for that. I am trying to add the item column to the loop without unpivoting it first. Do you understand what I mean? I can edit the original question to explain myself better if needed.

Comment: It would be best if you could update your question. And I am no longer able to reference the data, so I can't even revise my answer without the data.

Comment: I got the code on another question and didnt realize it. Dont understand it yet, but will get there.Thanks for your help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73584455/remove-column-name-from-chart-title-in-sns-relplot-and-keep-only-horizontal-grid

Answer (score 0):

Working Example below. I used seaborn to plot the bars but the idea is the same you can loop through the facets and increase a count. Starting from -1 so that your first count = 0, and use this as the axis label.

```
import seaborn as sns 

fig, ax = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=itemCount ,figsize=(30,10), sharey=True)  

df['Cost'] = df['Cost'].astype(float) 
count = -1 
variables = df['Item'].unique() 

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,itemCount , figsize=(25,70), sharex=False, sharey= False) 

for var in variables:
        count += 1 
        sns.barplot(ax=axs[count],data=df, x='Cost', y='City')
```

Comment: Trying to stick to matplotlib for learning purposes. Do you know how to do it without seaborn?

Comment: Sorry about that :( . Above solution does the trick

Comment: It does, thanks for  showing the sns solution. It will come handy in the future.